# Debian packages in private repository not visible in Muon

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, debian, muon-package-manager

I'm currently building my own Debian packages using `dpkg-buildpackage` and uploading them to a local repository which runs with `mini-dinstall`.

The repository is successfully added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the packages are possible to install using `apt-get install <mypackage>`, however they are neither searchable nor visible in Muon. When I select my source nothing is listed (but are for some other sources).

Am I missing something during the Debian package creation, e.g. is there any requirements on the packages themselves to make them appear?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm currently using Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Muon (KDE Software) is like Gnome software, by default it shows only graphical tools. Filtering out some Debian package categories mainly used by advanced users.

- Muon → View → Show technical packages

[image: muon - show adv packages]